# Are non-characters allowed in MS Access DB password?

Tags: .net, ms-access, enterprise-library

I was tasked with retrieving lost password to MS Access database that comes with a piece of software.

I tried a tool for that but returned string looks corrupted including "characters" like: †‡Δ and others that don't seam to be actual characters at all. However the db file is not corrupted because the software that comes with it has no problem getting data from that db.

I then tried injecting into the app at runtime after it loaded and established connection to db. The app uses Enterprise Library so in my injected payload I call:

```
new DatabaseConfigurationView(ConfigurationManager.GetCurrentContext())
```

and from it I managed to get the db password as it is in app memory and I know (from analyzing decompiled code) it's the same one being used by app to successfully pull data from db. Turns out it's the same corrupt looking string the tool was giving me.

If I try to open the db with Microsoft Access app (Office) the password window won't even accept the string. Ctrl+v is ignored but works when pasting string of valid characters.

Is it possible that this string including non-characters is the actual password or am I missing something here?

Bear in mind I have no previous experience with Enterprise Library or Access databases.

Comment: Perhaps it was programmed by chinese persons? arabic? japanese? The world is big outside the window.

Comment: How would you define a "non-character" character? Anyway, Access passwords aren't *user* passwords. An application would have no problem using whatever characters it wanted to protect and open the database.

Comment: Coder was Polish but he might have used crazy characters on purpose. Thing is I tried testing this by installing and configuring "Arial Unicode MS"  font which is suppose to include characters from all around the world and it's still same non-characters.

Comment: OK so that seams to answer my question. So the new question would be: how do I allow my client to access the db without coding? The password didn't work in DbVisualizer and MS Access 2003 won't even allow me to enter it into textfield.

Comment: Change the password.

Comment: From what I understand the db is encrypted based on password so changing it alone would corrupt the db file?
Would have to decrypt and encrypt again using new pass?
Is there API to do that programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Following Panagiotis Kanavos reassurance and advice I wrote a standalone to connect to db using that weird password and it worked. I then changed password with:

```
OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = @"ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD [newpass] [oldpass]";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and now I can open the db with MS Access.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: How did you use the weird password in a connection string? I am dealing with a similarly weird MDB password and when I use it in a connection string I get the error 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification' (presumably due to the specific weird characters in the string).